# Bootstrap pull-right not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Simple question here using `Bootstrap3`. I wanted to create a sort of small filter that reloads the page below it. My requirement was to **align** this filter (two inputs and a small button) with the content sitting below it, making it fall **to the rightest position possible**.

I tried using `pull-right` class and indeed it pulled the filter right but there's still more room to fill. If you check the example I provided below, you'll see that **my objective is to align the button with the right side of the purple row**, but it fails.

I don't really understand why this happens, but I assume that it's related to some margin/padding issues with the rows.. I'm looking for an answer explaining why this happens so I can understand the problem and won't deal with it again :).

You can check my markup [by clicking here on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/d3ITPWzgX2)

Also I'll post my markup right here:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:slateblue;">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style="margin-top:3px;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>
      </form>
      </div><!-- main col 12-->
  </div><!--row-->
  <div class="row" style="background:slategrey; height:200px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your form-group is aligned as far to the right as possible – but the content within it is not. (Since you have only 4+4+2 wide columns in there, you might want to simply offset the first one of those by 2, by adding `col-xs-offset-2` class.)

Comment: Why don't you use `form-inline` instead of `form-horizontal` anyway?

Comment: @CBroe actually using that offset aligns the content right... So was it caused by the lack of columns, if you explain it in an answer I'll accept yours.
@KhalidT. I just used `form-horizontal` because I didn't know the inline one, I've searched a bit and I think is more appropiate, thanks!

Comment: @KhalidT. using `form-inline` messes up all the spacing between the inputs and the button :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form-group is aligned as far to the right as possible – but the content within it is not. You have only 4+4+2 wide columns in there, so you are “two columns short”, in the 12-column grid used by bootstrap.

You might want to simply offset the first one of those by 2, by adding `col-xs-offset-2` class – then the alignment should be closer to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 33):

For those who are using bootstrap4:

> Added `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` classes for responsive
> floats and removed `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` since they’re
> redundant to `.float-left` and `.float-right`.

More information from Bootstrap4 migration notes: [Here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#utilities)

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap column layout will basically split the row into 12 columns. Here you are only defining 10 out of the twelve columns, which is why you have space left on the right.

Try

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style="margin-top:3px;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: +1 useful answer too, although I accepted CBroe's one as he was the first user to point out the solution

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 5
Starting from bootstrap 5, `.float-left` and `.float-right` were deprecated and replaced as below:

`.float-left` was replaced with `.float-start` to float elements to the left.

`.float-right` was replaced with `.float-end` to float elements to the right.

```
<img src="img/aj-24.jpeg" class="float-start"/>
<img src="img/aj-24.jpeg" class="float-end"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Uses a 12 column grid:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  (Worth the read)

To make sure you don't have this white space you need to be using up all of the columns as I can see you are not

Here is how I would do your code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:slateblue;">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style="margin-top:3px;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For those who accidentally installed Bootstrap version 4.**

It seems like some keywords were changed in Bootstrap version 4. Probably the easiest way is to roll back Bootstrap to version 3. Simply because other parts of your website might also be affected and not work as intended initially.

```
npm uninstall bootstrap

npm install bootstrap@3
```